# Cannot read property "First Name" of undefined javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following basic javascript function that I call when an onClick event occurs

```
function testMe() {
    var oForm = document.forms["ExampleForm"]["First Name"].value;
    console.log(oForm);
    if (oForm == "") {
        window.alert("This is a test");
    }
    return false;
}
```

However each time I click on the button, I get the error `Cannot read property "First Name" of undefined javascript` in the console. The form element `First Name` exists and does the form name `ExampleForm`

What am I overlooking or doing wrong?

**EDIT 0**

Although the example I have running at http://jsfiddle.net/3Ayd8 works it does not work when I run the same code on a page on an internal website.

**EDIT 1**

Here is the output of `console.log(document.forms)`

```
<form method="post" action="sample.aspx" id="form">

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

function NewDocument(parentNodeId, classId){ 
    if (parent != window) { 
        parent.NewDocument(parentNodeId, classId); 
    } else { 
        window.top.document.location = '/default.aspx?section=content&action=new&nodeid=' + parentNodeId + '&classid=' + classId; 
    } 
}
function NotAllowed(action){ 
    if (parent != window) { 
        parent.NotAllowed('', action); 
    } else { 
        window.top.document.location = '/default.aspx?section=content&action=notallowed&subaction=' + action; 
    } 
}
function DeleteDocument(nodeId) { 
    if (parent != window) { 
        parent.DeleteDocument(nodeId); 
    } else { 
        window.top.document.location = '/default.aspx?section=content&action=delete&nodeid=' + nodeId; 
    } 
}
function EditDocument(nodeId) { 
    if (parent != window) { 
        parent.EditDocument(nodeId); 
    } else { 
        window.top.document.location = '//default.aspx?section=content&action=edit&nodeid=' + nodeId; 
    } 
}
//]]>
<input type="hidden" name="vmode" id="vmode" value="2">
</div>
<script src="/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%2fCMSScripts%2fcmsedit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=aK015nKOf8Jw44OCiklcSydFiWaSIB9l6ZwdCQaMAWlevtaFiOw7Urzac1pIZ9Rs0&amp;t=34d147fd" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=aK015nKOf8Jw44OCiklcSydFiWaSIB9l6ZwdCQaMAWm_idfkOBcdRXBrkc0cxAR10&amp;t=34d147fd" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" value="0">
</div>
    <div id="manPortal" style="background:none;">
    <div id="CMSHeaderPad" style="height: 22px; line-height: 0px; "></div><div id="CMSHeaderDiv" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: auto; z-index: 10000; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; ">
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
if ( (parent != null) && (parent.IsCMSDesk) ) { infoElem = document.getElementById('manPortal_pnlPreviewInfo'); if (infoElem) {if ( infoElem.style ) { infoElem.style.display = 'none'; } else { infoElem.display = 'none'; } }}
//]]>
</script><!-- -->
    </div>
</div><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('manScript', 'form', [], [], [], 90, '');
//]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js?v=0.4"></script>

    <div class="zoneMainContent">
<div class="one-col-layout">
    <div class="col-one">
    <script type="text/javascript">
function testMe() {
    console.log(document.forms);
    console.log(document.getElementById("ExampleForm"));
    return false;
}
</script>

    <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value=""> <input name="submit" onclick="return testMe();" type="submit" value="submit">

    </div>
</div>
        <div style="clear:both;line-height:0px;height:0px;"></div>
    </div>
</div></form>
```

Comment: is there a form with `name="ExampleForm"` on the page? Works fine if there is http://jsfiddle.net/x6U7g/

Comment: Pretty sure you can't have spaces in element names.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey can you post the html then (or jsfiddle that replicates)

Comment: Need to see the form. Please post a basic HTML page including the script to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @Esailija - Have created an example of the form at jsfiddle.net/3Ayd8

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey yes but it doesn't replicate the issue. The jsfiddle works fine.

Comment: @Esailija - Please see my latest comment to Rocket based on the suggest to include the statement `console.log(document.forms));

Comment: You're missing a `</script>` in your HTML example.

Comment: There's no `ExampleForm` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of "First Name" you should use "FirstName". This was not the main issue, because "ExampleForm" was not found in the document.
2. If you have "ExampleForm" in an iFrame and you try to reach it from the outer document then your attempt will be unsuccessful, you need to reach "ExampleForm" from the page inside the iFrame in this case
3. If your page is inside an iframe and you try to reach "ExampleForm" which is in the outer document then you can use the window.parent property

Comment: Thanks. The issue appears to be that the CMS I am using wraps all content including the form I am creating within a parent form which is hidden. So in essence it is a form within a form. How do  I overcome such as issue?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to overcome your issue, but unfortunately you didn't share enough data with us regarding your problem and the best I can do with this amount of information is to give general advices, like above. From your last comment your problem sounds like referencing an iFrame inside another iFrame from the main document. Is this your case? If not, what is your issue, can you share more information?

Comment: There is no iframe. Within the CMS, I have the ability to insert HTML elements via 'Source' akin to any other CMS. I created my form inside the 'Source' and saved the page. The form elements appear fine on the page however when I look at the contents of the log there is no mention of the form tag element however it appears in the `View Source`. Mind boggling.

Comment: Can you share your html or something similar? Honestly I can't help you without enougn information.

Comment: I have included the output of `console.log(document.forms))`. As mentioned it appears the form tag element for `First Name` does not appear but it does when I `View Source`

Answer (score 2):

You can't have spaces in an element's name or ID.

This is according to the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the question?  Maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: w3 validator says it's valid in html401 transitional and html5. Do you have html5 specs on this? Furthermore, the error wouldn't be caused from this because it's the form that's undefined.

Comment: @Esailija: In HTML5, it says the ID attribute can't have spaces ([spec](http://developers.whatwg.org/elements.html#the-id-attribute)).  Not sure about name, I can't find anywhere in the spec that says the allowed characters for name.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Uhh, your example works fine... What's the issue?

Comment: @Rocket - Works fine in jsfiddle but not when I run it from an existing page on an internal website.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Then clearly something else is wrong elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @Rocket - What else could be the issue because if I remove everything but the alert, it works.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Try to `console.log(document.forms)` and `console.log(document.forms["ExampleForm"])`.  Just to make sure.

Comment: @Rocket - I did as you suggested and apparently the CMS system I am inserting the code into has a hidden form which apparently my form is part of. The second `console.log` statement returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space from the FirstName of the filed First Name in the form ExampleForm.

```
function testMe() {
    var oForm = document.forms["ExampleForm"]["FirstName"].value;
    console.log(oForm);
    if (oForm == "") {
        window.alert("This is a test");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I did that as well as renamed the form element name to `FirstName` however still get an error.

Comment: Can you please post your html code above.it will give a better perspective.